# Bracha on Post's Good Morenings Waffle Crunch cereal

Tags: blessing

The **star K** brachos list below http://www.star-k.org/resource/list/UK0XE63K/Cereals_and_their_Brachos has a cereal made by **Post** called Waffle Crisp with the proper Bracha. Does anyone know whether **Good Morenings Waffle Crunch** cereal by **Post** is the same one as on the list from the Star K?

Comment: Since it is "Good Mornings" cereal, the bracha is Mode Ani

Comment: @ClintEastwood - Purim Torah? :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to reviews on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RA3V36G9A45PP/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00NEZAELI) and [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Post-Good-Morenings-Waffle-Crunch-Cereal-21-oz/21265991) this cereal is the same as
Waffle Crisp.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffle_Crisp

Answer (score 4):

According [to the ingredients](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Post-Good-Morenings-Waffle-Crunch-Cereal-21-oz/21265991) this would be a Mezonos with an Al Hamichya.

> Ingredients: Wheat Flour, Sugar, Corn Flour, Whole Grain Oat Flour,
>   Partially Hydrogenated Soybean Oil, Salt, Caramel Color, Natural and
>   Artificial Flavor, BHT Added to Packing Material to Preserve Product
>   Freshness.Vitamins and Minerals: Niacinamide, Reduced Iron, Zinc Oxide
>   (Source of Zinc), Vitamin B6, Vitamin A Palmitate, Riboflavin (Vitamin
>   B2), Thiamin Mononitrate (Vitamin B1), Folic Acid, Vitamin B12,
>   Vitamin D.

Comment: +0. Why do you think there's sufficient wheat flour in an average-sized bowl for an Al Ha'michya?

Comment: @unforgettableid Generally, ingredients are listed in descending volume order. With wheat flour being #1 and oat flour being #4, I think in this case, it seems safe to assume that these two comprise the majority to make this mezonot. Most of the rest of the ingredients are colors and chemicals. I'm not as concerned about the debate on the before bracha as to the bracha one would have to make on his health after eating this junk for 20 years.

Comment: Ah okay; fair answer.